# AngularJS: compile the directive template with dynamic scope while cloning a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, clone

I am trying to generate multiple templates using directive, I am able to generate multiple layouts but unable to allocate different id's to those layouts.

Please find the detailed information/ code in the plunker

```
  <http://plnkr.co/edit/qIde3nZqCv6tHV2wVYEU?p=preview>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please submit relevant code here instead of linking it.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg it is a bit long code, could you please have a look into this plunker for detailed code: http://plnkr.co/edit/qIde3nZqCv6tHV2wVYEU?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, angularjs is not really my thing. But perhaps someone else will pick it up.